# Using the <code> or <pre> tags in Jade templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, haml, pug

Is there way to include line breaks in code text you want to display in a jade template.

say you are doing something like this.

```
html
   head
   body
      pre var config = {"theme":"dark",api-key:"fjhb3u2h4busifhu13u232iuiwrew"} \n
          var service = LameService.init(config)
```

I dont know how to get the service init line to break into the second line. it displays all in one line like this

```
var config = {"theme":"dark",api-key:"fjhb3u2h4busifhu13u232iuiwrew"} \n var service = LameService.init(config)
```

Comment: Solved! I had to use the style "white-space:pre" to achieve that...just for anyone who cares to know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you found your answer, but you could also use `|` which would put in a line break

```
html
   head
   body
      pre var config = {"theme":"dark",api-key:"fjhb3u2h4busifhu13u232iuiwrew"}
        | var service = LameService.init(config)
```